# How to reinstall the packages that has been removed in the last remove command in arch linux?

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, i3, pacman

So recently I have installed Manjato linux with i3wm. It came with urxvt and urxvt-perls pre installed so I've switched to st terminal emulator and decided to remove urxvt-perls, and urxvt-perls.
So I ran 
pacman -Rcns urxvt-perls

And even before seeing what is being removed I confirmed the removal. At it removed crucial packages such as dunst, nitrogen and lot of other packages required by i3. So i3 crashed. So im looking for a way to get things working again. What would be a clean way to fix this situation?

Comment: Reinstalling a package will automatically pull in any missing dependencies. But that won't cover anything else that you accidentally deleted

Answer (score 2):

### The first thing to do is find out which packages were actually removed:

This should be logged to **/var/log/pacman.log**.
It depends on whether the system is still usable; you are able to login to a shell or not:

### If yes:

- With: `nano /var/log/pacman.log`     inspect the log file, you will
  find line(s) that says something like

  `[Date...] [PACMAN] 'Runing pacman -Rcns urxvt-perls'`

  The lines that follows are interesting,
  especially      `[Date...] [ALPM] removed ....urxvt-perls....`
  Hit **Ctrl-x** to exit nano  (substitute nano with editor of you
  choice, vi, vim...)
- With: `grep -i urxvt-perls /var/log/pacman.log`     you can "search"
  for lines containing urxvt-perls or if removing it was the last action
  you did, you can instead:     `tail /var/log/pacman.log` . tail -n X to
  print last X lines.
- Take notice of what else was removed.           Now reinstall with:
  `pacman -S pkg1 pkg2 pkgn`        The problem
  here is that you might install also the dependencies as  [explicit vs
  dependency](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Installation_reason). So avoid installing the dependencies since they will
  be installed anyway.

### If not:

- Reboot the system and when you see the grub boot menu, hit **e** and
     with arrow keys go down to the line that starts with **linux**....
- Go to the end of that line and append **init=/bin/sh** and hit 
     **Ctrl-x** to boot with your changed [kernel parameters](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_parameters). You would be presented with a root shell. Follow the the previous steps; find the package(s) and reinstall.
- If that doesn't help either, boot from the install media and
     [chroot](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Restore_the_GRUB_Bootloader#Chroot_into_your_existing_Manjaro_Installation) to the installed system.

Not sure if that is the cleanest way though. Just try installing the important packages first; [i3-wm](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/i3-wm/) and see if you get your Desktop back.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to reinstall packages. My guess is that the system boot stops before loading the gui - so the way to solve it is pretty simple and fast:

1. Boot the system until it stops, maybe wait 2 minutes to be sure it is full started.
2. Press ctrl + alt + F1 .... F6 to get into another tty. F1 stands for tty1, F2 for tty2 and so on, test every one until you got a login window.
3. Log into the tty with your user name and your password - should be your admin account with root rights. Boom - there you are in.
4. Next follow the arch [guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/I3). Meaning if your i3 is cluttered it would be `sudo pacman -Syu i3-wm`
5. Than either reboot the system with `sudo pacman reboot` and and it should start up again if really just some packages are missing or starting it with `startx /usr/bin/i3` and your desktop should be up and running again :)
6. If it doesn't start automatically you have to enable its boot sequence but that shouldn't be necessary since the system already were running.
   Add an exec command in `~/.config/i3/config` file. For example:

   exec terminator

Alternatively, you can use [XDG Autostart](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_Autostart).

If that doesn't work you can boot in with an usb stick, "chroot" your system
to the main drive and follow along from point 4. Leave me a comment if you need more help and I edit this post for you and add how to chroot it.

Actually fixing this kind of problems are how arch linux is glowing and sparking because it is that easy done without having to pull out all the dependencies since pacman is doing that for you. I hope you have fun with your arch and learning new stuff.

The 3rd way would be reinstalling the whole system but that shouldn't be necessary.

*If this solved your answer and got your system up and running again, please click on the arrow under the upvote to make it not shown in the "unsolved" section from stackexchange.com :)*